# Bash - Read in a file and replace multiple spaces with just one comma

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to write a bash script that will take in a file with spaces and output the same file, but comma delimited. I figured out how to replaces spaces with commas, but I've run into a problem: there are some rows that have a variable number of spaces. Some rows contain 2 or 3 spaces and some contain as many as 7 or 13. Here's what I have so far:

```
sed 's/ /,/g' $varfile > testdone.txt
```

$varfile is the file name that the user gives.

But I'm not sure how to fix the variable space problem. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' "$varfile"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a job for `sed`.  `tr` is more appropriate:

```
$ printf 'foo      bar\n' | tr -s ' ' ,
foo,bar
```

The `-s` tells `tr` to squash multiple occurrences.  Also, you can generalize with `tr -s '[:space:]' ,` (which will replace newlines, perhaps undesirable) or `tr -s ' \t' ,` to handle spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the `+` quantifier to match one *or more*

Assuming GNU sed

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' file
# or
sed -E 's/ +/,/g' file
```

With GNU **basic** regular expressions, the "one or more" quantifier is `\+`
With GNU **extended** regular expressions, the "one or more" quantifier is `+`

Comment: `sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g'` should work with any POSIX-compliant version of `sed`.